# Disable AJAX Calendar with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

How to disable the [Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) in a page using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. Disable JavaScript.
Seriously, though: We can't help you disable it if we don't know what activates it.

Comment: sorry was editing post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script i found from msdn

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function enableCalendar(){
                $get("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").disabled = false;
                $get('btnDisable').disabled = false;
                $get('btnEnable').disabled = true;
                $find('myCEID').set_button($get("<%=ImageButton1.ClientID%>"));
            }
            function disableCalendar(){
                $get("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
                $get('btnDisable').disabled = true;
                $get('btnEnable').disabled = false;
                $find('myCEID').hide();
                $common.removeHandlers($find('myCEID')._button, $find('myCEID')._button$delegates);
                $find('myCEID')._button = null;
            }
        </script>
```

you can check full answer realted to this over there : [**disable CalendarExtender**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1181409.aspx)